# Privacy of WhatsApp messages

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, privacy

My husband has taken over my Android since he's the account holder. I'm wondering can he get any call or text information from my WhatsApp off of the T-Mobile printout of my phone activity?

Comment: In what way has he "taken over" your phone? Please [edit] your question and give full details if you want accurate answers.

Answer (score 2):

No, he shouldn't be able to, as far as I know WhatsApp encrypts the calls and messages that are sent through your carrier's data service.

Anyways usually if you ask a phone carrier to produce a call and message log for a line they'll show you the calls and messages you've made and received through actual SMS messaging and cellular calls. Since WhatsApp passes the encrypted data from your device as data calls there would be no way for T-Mobile to show the contents or recipients of the calls or messages.

Comment: If someone has full access to the device (as which I read "taken over my Android"), that does not matter. Yes, WA does E2E encryption – but that only means stuff is encrypted *while in transit.* On both ends, it is decrypted.